# how to replace character in string

Tags: c, string, char, character

```c
int main(){
 
   char* str = "bake", *temp = str;
   char alpha [] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
       for (int i = 0 ; temp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; alpha[j] != '\0'; j++) {
                temp[i] = alpha[j];
                printf("%s\n",temp);
              }
          temp = str;
       }
   return 0;
}
```

Why am I trying to replace a character in a particular location it falls to me?
i want it print me like that

```
  i = 0 (index 0 he change only the first char).
    aake
    bake
    cake
    dake
    ....
    i = 1(index 1 he change only the second char).
    bake
    bbke
    bcke
    bdke
    ....
```

i don't understand why `temp[i] = alpha[j]`
not work... what i need to do that i can change the char.
thank you a lot for helps

![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0onF.jpg

Comment: For starters, it's undefined behaviour to change the string produced by a string literal. `char *str = "bake";` should be `char str[] = "bake";`

Comment: a literal (constant) string cannot be modified. Note out of that your algo try to fill *temp* with the last non null character of alpha, so zzzz...zz

Comment: `*temp = str` looks really weird, and doesn't jive with how `temp` is used later. Did you mean to use `char *temp = strdup(str);`?

Comment: @bruno how i can change?

Comment: Re "*`alpha[j] != '\0'`*", `'\0'` isn't  anywhere in `alpha`

Comment: @arieldomchik what do you want to do ?

Comment: This last comment of mine explains the error you got

Comment: Please fix your formatting and include the error message *as text* (You can also include the screenshot, but don't force us to look deal with a screenshot when it's not necessary)

Comment: @ikegami thefact the string cannot be modified comes before the missing null character in alpha

Comment: i add the screen shot you see where i got the error...

Comment: @arieldomchik as already said you cannot modify the a literal string, so you cannot modify `temp[i]`

Comment: @bruno so you have way to do that?

Comment: @arieldomchik  as already proposed you can do `char str[] = "bake"; char * temp = str;`, but the other problems will come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, there are a couple of mistakes in your code. First of all, as stated by [bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458991/bruno) you cannot modify a literal string. Secondly, when you write *temp=str you are saying "the pointer temp now points to the same adress as str", in short, doing this, if you modify the array in temp you will modify the array in str as well, and vice-versa, because they are the same.

Below you have a possible solution using malloc to create a new array in temp and strcpy to copy str to temp after each outter cycle

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

   char str[]= "bake",*temp;
   temp=malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));
   strcpy(temp,str);
   char alpha [] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
   for (int i = 0 ; temp[i] != '\0'; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; alpha[j] != '\0'; j++) {
          temp[i] = alpha[j];
          printf("%s\n",temp);
      }
       strcpy(temp,str);
   }
    
   return 0;
}
```