# strtok does not move on to the next iteration

Tags: c, string, strtok

```
SpellingSuggestion* spellingCheck(){
    char text [] = "iam afraid youare about to become teh immexdiate pst president of teh eing alive club ha ha glados";
    char* filePath = "/Users/ronijackvituli/Desktop/Assignment/dictionary.txt";
    char* pch;
    HashTable* ht = initTable(WORDS, HASH_FUNCTION);
    SpellingSuggestion* head = NULL , *list = head;
    if(parseWordsToTable(filePath, ht)){
        pch = strtok(text, " "); ..
        while (pch != NULL) {
            if(head == NULL){
                head = BuildNodeSuggestion(pch, getWordSuggestions(ht,pch));
                list = head;
            }else{
                list->next = BuildNodeSuggestion(pch, getWordSuggestions(ht,pch));
                list = list->next;
            }
            pch = strtok(NULL, " "); //Does not move on to the next iteration
        }
    }else{
        printf("THE WORDS NOT INSERT TO HASHTABLE.\n\n");
    }
    return head;
}
```

pch takes the first word "iam" sends to the functions I built everything returns correctly but as soon as it reaches the line

> pch = strtok (NULL, "");

To move to the next iteration ie to the word "afraid" he does not do it and straight pch = NULL

Comment: You must not try to modify string literals.

Comment: @MikeCAT so maybe you have some idea how i can take word word? without to change the string?

Comment: The solution is the same as [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457841/how-to-replace-character-in-string). You shouldn't modify a read-only string literal so use a character array on the stack or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Blastfurnace ok i did but now in pch = strtok(NULL, " "); it take only NULL and does not advance to the next word for example the first word is "iam" and next word need to be "afarid" but he take "NULL"

Comment: It works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/Sydiaq07O